# Can I drop not null constraints online in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table with quite many rows (more than 300 000 000). I want to remove not null constraint for one of the columns by running the next SQL query while the database is still under load (since the table is big, it may take about 10 minutes):

```
ALTER TABLE DECLARATION
    ALTER COLUMN LOCAL_REFERENCE_NUMBER VARCHAR(22) NULL WITH (ONLINE = ON);
```

I expect this `ONLINE = ON` option to ensure that the table is not locked during the update to make sure that the applications that use the database can still do it during the update.

However, [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/guidelines-for-online-index-operations?view=sql-server-2016) say that `ONLINE = ON` is only applicable for adding and removing indexes as well as *primary key or unique* constraints, i.e., as it seems from the official documentation, this option has no effect for the not null constraints.

Is it indeed the case, or the documentation is just not full? If that is the case, what is so special about dropping not null constraints that it cannot be done online?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you have things the wrong way around. You cannot specify the option because it's *meaningless*, not because the operation cannot be done "online". So far as I recall, it's actually a metadata only operation so doesn't even touch the table.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, does it mean that if I want to, say, drop an index, then I can do it online, but if I want to drop the not null constraint, I cannot do it online, so I have to stop my applications?

Comment: ..@yaskovdev .. is the datatype of the column changed/altered too?

Comment: @lptr, no, the datatype stayed the same.

Comment: I have run the alter table query for a table with 3 million records, it looks like @Damien_The_Unbeliever was right: the time the query takes does not depend on a size of a table, it always runs very fast.

Comment: ..@yaskovdev... it depends on the datatype. non-nullable fixed size columns are stored on the fixed-size part of the data row (left side). variable size are stored in the variable-size part(right-side). Since the column is of a variable size datatype (varchar) already..then it is already stored in the variable-part of the row and changing the nullability does not require any data changes. If the column was char not null then altering to varchar would have to rearrange every row in the data pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in commment section this operation should be metadata operation only(if no data type changes occured):

```
ALTER TABLE DECLARATION
    ALTER COLUMN LOCAL_REFERENCE_NUMBER VARCHAR(22) NULL;
```

It could be verified by setting [Extended Event session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and observing  `sqlserver.compressed_alter_column_is_md_only` event (SQL Server 2016+)